# Using the response from Http get json

Tags: android, json, http

Using the below code I am able to get from the login/json the json information.

How can I convert that into something I can use? 
I am trying to determine right now whether or not the user exists or not. 
if it doesn't it returns:

```
 `{
    "user": null,
    "sessionId": null,
    "message": "Invalid email/username and password"
}
```

any guidance would be great.
`

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9000/auth/login/json");
         // Building post parameters
        // key and value pair

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "user"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", "password"));

        // Url Encoding the POST parameters
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Making HTTP Request
        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use google GSON to map the json to you model.

or simply

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonresponse.toString());

String user = obj.optString("user",null);

In this way you can access the response.

if(user == null){
  // not authorised or login
}
```

Comment: How would i use that null? can I use it by doing if(user=null)?

Answer (score -1):

First:

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "user"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", "password"));

    // Url Encoding the POST parameters
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    }
```

it is not correct, use next:

```
  JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
  body.put("user", "user");
  body.put("pw", "password");
  String strBody = body.toString();

  httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(strBody, "UTF-8"));
```

For parsing json strings you can use gson library, it is very good as for me. Just create a model of response, for example:

```
   public class SessionResponse implements Serializable{
     @SerializedName("user")
     private User user;

     @SerializedName("sessionId")
     private String sessionId;

     @SerializedName("message")
     private String message;

   }
```

Then just use next:

```
   String yourResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
   SessionResponse sessionResponse = new Gson().fromJSON(yourResponse, SessionResponse.class);
```

Now you have object of SessionResponse and can do with it anything. Just notice that every class that you want to convert should be marked as "Serializable" with implementing Serializable interface.

Comment: Why you are serialising the model?